# Markdown in iPython Notebook: how to highlight code?

Tags: syntax, markdown, jupyter-notebook

In Markdown, how do you `highlight code` <--- just like that. I don't know how to search for it because I'm not sure what it's called. I also don't know what the little dashes are called either. I tried doing what I would do in SO, but it just reads it as normal text

---

**Update:**

This is what I have:

- `foo` in SO it actually shows the hilighting

  - `bar` whereas in iPython Notebook, it doesn't, it only changes the fontstyle

Comment: Use backticks (`) to wrap your code for inline code blocks and triple backticks or minimum of four spaces indentation (depending which parser you are using) for full code blocks.

Comment: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code

Comment: @Terry I tried using backticks in a list, but it didn't work. The font looks different, but it doesn't highlight it like it does in stackoverflow or like i've seen on some blogs

Comment: @AlanH Can you reproduce your issue here, or share the code that is problematic? Also, if all fails you can always fall back to using HTML, i.e. `<code>`—it would also work for Markdown.

Comment: @AlanH, you're not really "highlighting" code here, either. You're generating `<code>` tags which are a [semantic way of representing source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code). Stack Overflow *happens* to add a grey background to `<code>`, but that's incidental. If they chose to change the way they styles these tags tomorrow, they could. There is nothing inherent in backticks that suggests highlighting.

Answer (score 5):

You're making <\code> sections.  They're not styled the same way as SO.  Add this cell to a notebook and they will have a similar style.

```
%%HTML
<style> code {background-color : lightgrey !important;} </style>
```

If you want more specificity then use `.rendered_html code{...` in a custom style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but **backtick** `` ` `` is the way to go, just like here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

In short: **Use <`code`> tag**

In normal cases backticks work for `highlighting` text but are printed as literal characters **when inside html lists**.

A part of [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) written using markdown

```
Training the neural network model requires the following steps:

<ol>
    <li>Feed the training data into the model. In this example, the training data is in the <code>train_images</code> and <code>train_labels</code> arrays.</li>
    <li>The model learns to associate the images and labels.</li>
    <li>You ask the model to make predictions about a test set -- in this example the test_images array.</li>
    <li>Verify the predictions match the labels from the <code>test_labels</code> array.</li>
</ol>
```

### Output

(As seen in jupyter notebook)

Training the neural network model requires the following steps:

1. Feed the training data into the model. In this example, the training data is in the `train_images` and `train_labels` arrays.
2. The model learns to associate the images and labels.
3. You ask the model to make predictions about a test set -- in this example the test_images array.
4. Verify the predictions match the labels from the `test_labels` array.